# Changing samplerate and byterate of a wav file without encountering problems opening the file?

Tags: c, audio, wav, alter, tweak

I'm trying to write the contents of a 503,196-byte wav file into another and double the samplerate/byterate in order to double the speed. However, I'm having trouble reading in the data from the input file and writing it to the output file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct WAVE {
           char ChunkID[4];
           unsigned int ChunkSize;
           char Format[4];
           char Subchunk1ID[4];
           unsigned int Subchunk1Size;
           unsigned short int AudioFormat;
           unsigned short int NumChannels;
           unsigned int SampleRate;
           unsigned int ByteRate;
           unsigned short int BlockAlign;
           unsigned short int BitsPerSample;
           char Subchunk2ID[4];
           unsigned int Subchunk2Size;
    } wav;
    FILE *original, *fast;
    original = fopen("Alejandro_project.wav", "rb");
    fast = fopen("Alejandro_fast.wav", "wb");
    if (original == NULL) {
                 printf("File does not exist.\n");
                 return 0;
    }
    fread(&wav, 1, 44, original);
    unsigned short int data[12 * wav.SampleRate]
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Subchunk2Size / 2; i++)
        fread(&data[i], 1, 2, original);
    fwrite(&wav, 1, 44, fast);
    unsigned int fastSampleRate = wav.SampleRate * 2;
    unsigned int fastByteRate = 2 * fastSampleRate;
    fseek(fast, 24, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&fastSampleRate, 4, 1, fast);
    fseek(fast, 28, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&fastByteRate, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(data, 1, 2, original);
    fclose(fast);
    fclose(original);
}
```

Comment: You should probably pack your WAVE struct (`#pragma pack(1)` or `__attribute__((__packed__))` or whatever)... it may have unwanted padding.

Comment: Does Alejandro_fast.wav already contain a copy of the file when the program starts? It doesn't look like you are writing the rest of file after the header to the target file

Comment: @samgak Actually, now that you mention it, even if Alejandro_fast.wav *did* (originally) contain a copy, it'd be discarded because the file is opened with "wb"... maybe "r+b" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.. for starters, you need to ensure the struct for your WAVE header is packed so that there won't be unexpected padding within the struct that would misalign some of the fields and increase the size of the structure.  Otherwise, you've likely got two bytes of extra padding after each of the `unsigned short int` members.

```
#pragma pack(push,1) /* for VC, may also work for GCC */
struct WAVE {
     /* ...struct contents... */
} wav;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Second, it looks like you're trying to simply overwrite the SampleRate and ByteRate members in the new file while leaving the rest unchanged.  This will only work if the new file is already a copy of the old one.  If so, you also need to change the mode you open the new file with to "r+b" (read mode + writing) instead of "wb" (write mode) so that the existing file contents won't be discarded.

There's also an error when you attempt to write the header.  This line:

```
fread(original, 1, 44, fast);
```

Should probably have been:

```
fwrite(&wav, 44, 1, fast);
```

to write 44 bytes from `wav` to the new file, rather than reading from the new file and using the old file's `FILE *` as the destination.

---

If the new file is *not* already a copy of the old one, you would need to copy over the rest of the file too (including the other parts of the header).  In this case, it's probably easiest to (once the files are opened):

1. Read the header from the old file into `wav`

   ```
   fread(&wav, sizeof(wav), 1, original);
   ```
2. Modify the `SampleRate` and `ByteRate` fields

   ```
   wav.SampleRate *= 2;
   wav.ByteRate *= 2;
   ```
3. Write the entire modified `wav` header to the new file

   ```
   fwrite(&wav, sizeof(wav), 1, fast);
   ```
4. Copy the remainder of the old file to the new file in a loop

   ```
   char buf[1024];
   int count;
   while ((count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), original)) > 0)
       fwrite(buf, 1, count, fast);
   ```

..and then close the files and return.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I removed the struct just to see what I was doing. I'm going to incorporate the struct back in once I finish my final project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *original, *fast, *slow, *slowdown;
    unsigned int ChunkSize, Subchunk1Size, Subchunk2Size, RIFFSize, fmtSize, dataSize, SampleRate, ByteRate;
    unsigned short int AudioFormat, NumChannels, BlockAlign, BitsPerSample;
    char ChunkID[5], Format[5], Subchunk1ID[5], Subchunk2ID[5];
    ChunkID[4] = '\0';
    Format[4] = '\0';
    Subchunk1ID[4] = '\0';
    Subchunk2ID[4] = '\0';
    char path[FILENAME_MAX], dfast[FILENAME_MAX], dslow[FILENAME_MAX], dslowdown[FILENAME_MAX];
    printf("Enter path to Alejandro_project.wav file: ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    strcpy(dfast, path);
    dfast[strlen(path) - 21] = '\0';
    strcpy(dslow, dfast);
    strcpy(dslowdown, dslow);
    strcat(dfast, "Alejandro_fast.wav");
    strcat(dslow, "Alejandro_slow.wav");
    strcat(dslowdown, "Alejandro_slowdown.wav");
    original = fopen(path, "rb");
    if (!original) {
        printf("Error: file does not exist.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fread(ChunkID, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&ChunkSize, 4, 1, original);
    fread(Format, 4, 1, original);
    fread(Subchunk1ID, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&Subchunk1Size, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&AudioFormat, 2, 1, original);
    fread(&NumChannels, 2, 1, original);
    fread(&SampleRate, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&ByteRate, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&BlockAlign, 2, 1, original);
    fread(&BitsPerSample, 2, 1, original);
    fread(Subchunk2ID, 4, 1, original);
    fread(&Subchunk2Size, 4, 1, original);
    fmtSize = Subchunk1Size + 8;
    dataSize = Subchunk2Size + 8;
    RIFFSize = ChunkSize + 8 - (fmtSize + dataSize);
    printf("RIFF Size:     %d\n", RIFFSize);
    printf("fmt Size:      %d\n", fmtSize);
    printf("data Size:     %d\n\n", dataSize);
    printf("ChunkID:       %s\n", ChunkID);
    printf("ChunkSize:     %d\n", ChunkSize);
    printf("Format:        %s\n\n", Format);
    printf("Subchunk1ID:   %s\n", Subchunk1ID);
    printf("Subchunk1Size: %d\n", Subchunk1Size);
    printf("AudioFormat:   %d\n", AudioFormat);
    printf("NumChannels:   %d\n", NumChannels);
    printf("SampleRate:    %d\n", SampleRate);
    printf("ByteRate:      %d\n", ByteRate);
    printf("BlockAlign:    %d\n", BlockAlign);
    printf("BitsPerSample: %d\n\n", BitsPerSample);
    printf("Subchunk2ID:   %s\n", Subchunk2ID);
    printf("Subchunk2Size: %d\n", Subchunk2Size);
    fseek(original, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fast = fopen(dfast, "wb");
    unsigned int fastSampleRate = SampleRate * 2;
    unsigned int fastByteRate = 2 * fastSampleRate;
    fwrite(ChunkID, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&ChunkSize, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(Format, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(Subchunk1ID, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&Subchunk1Size, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&AudioFormat, 2, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&NumChannels, 2, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&fastSampleRate, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&fastByteRate, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&BlockAlign, 2, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&BitsPerSample, 2, 1, fast);
    fwrite(Subchunk2ID, 4, 1, fast);
    fwrite(&Subchunk2Size, 4, 1, fast);
    short int data;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Subchunk2Size / 2; i++) {
        fread(&data, 2, 1, original);
        fwrite(&data, 2, 1, fast);
    }
    fclose(fast);
    fseek(original, 0, SEEK_SET);
    slow = fopen(dslow, "wb");
    unsigned int slowSampleRate = SampleRate / 2;
    unsigned int slowByteRate = 2 * slowSampleRate;
    fwrite(ChunkID, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&ChunkSize, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(Format, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(Subchunk1ID, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&Subchunk1Size, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&AudioFormat, 2, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&NumChannels, 2, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&slowSampleRate, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&slowByteRate, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&BlockAlign, 2, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&BitsPerSample, 2, 1, slow);
    fwrite(Subchunk2ID, 4, 1, slow);
    fwrite(&Subchunk2Size, 4, 1, slow);
    for (i = 0; i < Subchunk2Size / 2; i++) {
        fread(&data, 2, 1, original);
        fwrite(&data, 2, 1, slow);
    }
    fclose(slow);    
    fclose(original);
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To double the speed, you can not just change `sample rate` or `byte-rate` in the WAV header. If you do so, it will play fast but will sound weird due to wrong pitch. Instead, you **need to use a proper Sample Rate Conversion (SRC) library** to convert your input WAV file to an output WAV file with faster sample rate.